# How to say complex sentences in Lojban (understanding the basics of gismu)?

Tags: lojban, sentence-structure

I *finally* delved into Lojban, and it is great so far! I don't fully understand yet, but getting closer. There is [this list of gismu](https://gist.github.com/lynn/c42d17ca3408cd760bd619096762f1cf) totalling 1342 items. Each one is linked to a page such as [cmima](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Lojban/cmima), where they say the mathematical function such as that one:

> member; x1 is a member/element of set x2; x1 belongs to group x2; x1 is amid/among/amongst group x2.

Or [basti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Lojban/basti):

> replace; x1 replaces/substitutes for/instead of x2 in circumstance x3; x1 is a replacement/substitute.

The examples I've seen so far are [basic](https://mw.lojban.org/papri/Lojban_grammar_examples):

> **ko'a dunda ko'e ko'i** - *He, gives it to her.*

How do you insert long and complex phrases in each slot, basically? I only see 1 word per slot so far.

How would you say:

> [x1: The grumpy old man] gives [x2: the unbelievably brown and dry paper] [x3: to the mean and tired old lady]

Where can I find more information on how you construct these larger "phrases" to fill in the slots of the gismu? Or how would you explain how to write such a sentence?

As a newcomer, this information is seemingly missing from the introductory material.

Comment: Check out a tutorial like [la karda](http://ldlework.com/projects/cards/la-karda/).